# Creating a mobile app and a website using MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am creating a website/mobile app that has the following goals:

1. Need to render on mobile browser (android, iOS)
2. Need to render on a tablet on a browser (IPad etc)
3. Need to render it on a desktop browser
4. Need to create a mobile app bundled with PhoneGap

I am using KendoUI on the client side and ASP.NET MVC 4.

I need to make sure that I reuse code as much as possible.

Here's my plan:

1. For the mobile app, create plain HTML (as CSHTML cannot be used to bundle with PhoneGap), JS and Kendo mobile widgets
2. For mobile browser rendering, I will create a separate solution and create browser specific views (I assume I need 3? one for mobile browser, one for tablet, one for desktop browser). I'll use Kendo Web widgets
3. I need to reuse the server side code as much as possible (Controllers, data access EF layer etc). Do I need to use Web API for this?

Will this work? Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Frankly the only way to tell if it will work is to actually try it.

ASP.NET MVC 4 has the nice capability of rendering different views based on the device accessing the web site. This would help you create views for desktop, tablet and phone.

I strongly recommend exposing your business logic as services which return JSON. You could then consume your data from any platform and any technology. There are different ways to create a JSON service in .NET - WCF, ASP.NET MVC action methods, WebApi etc.